# How can I integrate pagination in Nextjs 13 beta ( with appDir )?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

Here is api url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/products/?page=2`

so, I need to change `/?page=$(number)`

Therefore I'm using NextJs 13 beta with appDir the `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` doesn't work on the `app/products/page.tsx` file. So how can I use pagination in that case ?

I am expecting to get the next page data and pages numbers and the current page is_active functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you mean is `store/products?page=2` instead of the `/` before the `?`.

To get the page number in the url the code should look like that:

```
const Page = async ({ searchParams }) => {
  const { page } = searchParams // page = 2
  
  return <h1>{page}</h1>
}
export default Page;
```

Comment: I wanna change the number and get the response

Comment: I mean, you can't create API pages not in the API directory or with the route.tsx file, so I am not sure exactly what you mean.